# How can I configure the Jenkins Pipeline UI for matrix jobs?

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

I am creating a trigger job that starts a batch of jobs using a matrix pipeline like this:
pipeline {
agent any

```
stages {
    stage ('Build') {
        matrix {
            axes {
                axis {
                    name 'PLATFORM'
                    values 'centos-6', 'centos-7', 'ubuntu-14.04', 'ubuntu-18.04'
                }
                axis {
                    name 'PROJECT'
                    values 'engine', 'documentation', 'monitoring'
                }
            }
            stages {
                stage ("building")
                {
                    steps {
                        build job: "${PROJECT}/${PLATFORM}", parameters:[], propagate:true, wait:true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

This works just fine, but the automatically generated user interface for the status report is somewhat suboptimal:

[image: Jekins UI snippet]

As you can see, there are two blocks, even though I only have one stage per cell. I would really like to get rid of that "Matrix" block to reduce the screen width for a quick overview. Is that possible?
Also, the blocks in the report turn green nearly instantly (I think once the job has been triggered.) I would like them to stay "neutral" until the triggered job has been finished. Is that possible?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that rendering of pipelines won't be optimized in the classic Jenkins UI anymore. Try the [Blue Ocean UI](https://www.jenkins.io/projects/blueocean/), which is available as a Jenkins plugin. It renders pipelines more pleasingly:

[image: Blue Ocean rendering]

Comment: On my Jenkins, matrixes are rendered as shown here https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-61280, it's impossible to tell which axis value is which.